# How to display error in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I use windows command line for running Node.js files.
When I execute the script window is hidden at once. So I can not see errors.
How to not close window Command line and to display errors?

Comment: How are you running the server when the command-line window is not open? When I running my NodeJS application with a command in CMD the window stays open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open a console first and then execute your script from there.

> Widows+R > type 'cmd' > OK

And in the console

```
C:\> cd C:\the\path\to\your\script
C:\> node yourScript.js
```

The console window will stay open